# Trying to build multiple multidimensional arrays based on static data in markup

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to organize results using JavaScript/jQuery. There are three variable with each result...

```
ID
City
Percentage
```

Some of the `City` variable are the same and I want to organize them in an array based on city and then sort them based on `Percentage`.

```
// Get all the data from each result; Build two arrays (1 with the data and one with just metro IDs).
    $('.result').each(function(){

        a_result.push({
            id              : $(this).attr('data-result');
            city            : $(this).attr('data-city'),
            percentage      : $(this).attr('data-percentage')
        });

        a_city_id.push($(this).attr('data-city'))
    });
```

Then I ...

```
// Remove duplicates from the array containing just the metro IDs.
    $.each(a_metro_region_id, function(index, value){

        if($.inArray(value, u_city_id) === -1) u_city_id.push(value);

    });
```

Next I'm trying to ..

```
// Count the different metro IDs then find and display the result with the highest percentage for each metro ID.
```

But this is where I get stuck. I can't seem to produce one new array for each different `City` and having them be ordered base don percentage and still contains the ID

Comment: You have 4 different arrays shown. Hard to figure out what is what. Create a demo in jsfiddle.net that includes some sample data and html as well as your current code